# Conversion of JQuery to Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

To find a DOM element and to traverse and to trigger the click event , I tried:

```
 $("#intrusionGroup1").closest("div").children("div").children("ul").children("li").children("div").children("a").click(function () {
                self.addIntrusion();

            });
```

I need to convert it to Javascript code base , but this did not work:

```
document.queryselector("#intrusionGroup1").closest("div").children(....)
```

It said `children` is not a function , even `find` is not a function.

How to convert the same to Pure Javascript code?

Comment: *"Conversion of JQuery to Javascript code"* It already is JavaScript code. You're trying to convert JavaScript code using jQuery into JavaScript code using the DOM. It's not a change of language, it's a change of API.

Comment: closest & children are still jquery functions

Answer (score 1):

> I need to convert it to Javascript code base , but this did not work ..
>
> ```
> document.queryselector("#intrusionGroup1").closest("div").children(....)
> ```

It should have said `queryselector` isn't a function, as it requires a capital `S`. If you'd used `querySelector`, they next error would be that `closest` is not a function, because the DOM doesn't have a `closest` method.

You'll need to define your own worker function that handles figuring out the "closest" part using `parentNode`. E.g., something *vaguely* like:

```
function closest(element, tagName) {
    while (element && element.tagName !== tagName) {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return element;
}
```

Unlike jQuery's `closest`, that only does a tag name check, not a CSS selector check (see [`element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) if you need a full CSS selector check).

`children` is a valid DOM property on elements.

So then you'd have:

```
var children = closest(document.queryQelector("#intrusionGroup1", "div").children;
```

but since you have an ID, you might look at `getElementById` instead:

```
var children = closest(document.getElementById("intrusionGroup1", "div").children;
```

Note that `children` is a property in the DOM, not a function.

Then you'll need to handle looping through the children at each level and weeding out the ones you don't want. But surely there must be a simpler way to do it. For instance, if you put an `id` on the `div` you're finding with `closest` (say, `intrusionGroupDiv1`), then it becomes:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("#intrusionGroupDiv1 > div > ul > li > div > a");
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer: *children* is a property of a *DOM* element, not a method like in *jQuery*.

Comment: @MarioSantini: *"`children` is a valid DOM property on elements...Note that children is a property in the DOM, not a function"*

Answer (score 0):

There is something fundanmentally wrong in your HTML structure if you have to use

```
$("#intrusionGroup1").closest("div").children("div").children("ul").children("li").children("div").children("a")
```

selector. Try with better usage of CSS classes on the elements which you want to click (e.g: a class="list-item-link") and then all you will need to do is:

```
$(".list-item-link").click(function () {
   $(this).addIntrusion();
});
```